# What am I doing wrong in this Phong Shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've been trying for some time now to debug this simple Phong-Shader and just came up short. The diffuse part is fine but the specular is not. It doesn't move with the camera.

**Here's from one side:**

[image: Here's from one side]

**And here from the other:**

[image: And here from the other]

As far as I can see, I did convert the Position to Viewspace, but, apparently, I made another mistake of some kind.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location : enable


layout(location=0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 vPosition;
out vec3 vNormal;

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uView;
uniform mat4 uProjection;

void main(void) 
{
    vPosition = vec3(uModel * vec4(aPosition,1.0f));
    vNormal =   vec3(uModel * vec4(aNormal,  0.0f));
    gl_Position = uProjection * uView * uModel * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}
```

And my Fragment Shader

```
#version 330

out     vec4 FragColor;

in      vec3 vPosition;
in      vec3 vNormal;

uniform mat4 uView;
uniform vec3 uColor;
uniform vec3 uLightpositions[10];
uniform vec3 uLightcolors[10];
uniform float uPhongSpecular;


void main(void)
{
    FragColor = vec4(0.4*uColor, 1.0);//Ambient Value
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        vec3 lVec = normalize(uLightpositions[i] - vPosition);
        vec3 nVec = normalize(vNormal);
        
        float diffuse = max(dot(lVec,nVec), 0);
        FragColor += 0.5* vec4(uLightcolors[i] * diffuse,0.0f);
        
        vec3 rVec = normalize(reflect(lVec,nVec));
        vec3 vVec = -normalize(vec3(uView * vec4(vPosition,1.0)));
        
        float specular = 0;
        if(dot(rVec,vVec) < 0.0)
        {
            specular = pow(max(dot(-rVec,vVec),0),uPhongSpecular);
        }
        FragColor += 0.2*vec4(uLightcolors[i] * specular,0.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip : the variable names hardly express what they represent. You can use names like `lightDirection` or `normal`, and even use prefixes for their space like `osNormal` for object space or `wsInLight` for the incoming light direction in world space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `dot(-rVec, vVec)`. `vVec` is a vector in view space, however, `rVec` is a vector in world space. Convert `rVec` from world space to view space:

<s>`vec3 rVec = normalize(reflect(lVec, nVec));`</s>

```c
vec3 rVec = normalize(mat3(uView) * reflect(lVec, nVec));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing wrong in addition to Rabbid76's answer is `if(dot(rVec,vVec) < 0.0)` is testing if the angle between the two is greater than 90 degrees. In other words, you are testing if the specular reflection is visible behind the model. You have to flip that from less-than to greater-than `>`.

Comment: That would be correct, if both rVec and vVec "originated" in the same spot, which they don't here due to how GLSL's reflect function works. Since the light vector is calculated as "vPosition to uLightpositions[i]", that means that rVec may be imagined as "the vector from uLightpositions[i] mirrored on nVec to vPosition". And with vVec being the vector from vPosition to the Camera, an angle greater than 90 degrees is what I need here. Granted it is a tad unintuitive that way, courtesy of my profs example.